# gulp throws an error: Path must be a string. Received

Tags: gulp

I'm using node v6.10.3.

**config.json**

```
{
```

"root": {
    "src": "./src",
    "dest": "./static",
    "dist": "./dist"
  },

"tasks": {
    "browserSync": {
      "port": 4500,
      "open": false,
      "server": {
        "baseDir": "./"
      }
    },

```
"static": {
  "src": "src",
  "dest": "static"
},

"js": {
  "src": "js",
  "dest": "static/js",
  "entries": {
    "app": ["./app.js"]
  },
  "extensions": ["js", "json"],
  "babel": {
    "presets": ["es2015", "stage-1"],
    "plugins": []
  },
  "extractSharedJs": false
},

"css": {
  "src": "scss",
  "dest": "css",
  "autoprefixer": {
    "browsers": ["> 0%"]
  },
  "sass": {
    "indentedSyntax": true,
    "includePaths": [
      "./node_modules/normalize.css"
    ]
  },
  "extensions": ["sass", "scss", "css"]
},

"html": {
  "src": "templates",
  "dest": "./",
  "dataFile": "data/global.json",
  "htmlmin": {
    "collapseWhitespace": true
  },
  "extensions": ["html", "json", "tpl"],
  "excludeFolders": ["layouts", "partials", "macros", "data", "components"]
},

"images": {
  "src": "img",
  "dest": "img",
  "extensions": ["jpg", "png", "svg", "gif"]
},

"fonts": {
  "src": "fonts",
  "dest": "fonts",
  "extensions": ["woff2", "woff", "eot", "ttf", "svg"]
},

"iconFont": {
  "src": "svg-font",
  "dest": "fonts",
  "sassDest": "generated",
  "extensions": ["woff2", "woff", "eot", "ttf", "svg"]
},

"svgsprites": {
  "src": "svg",
  "dest": ".",
  "extensions": ["svg"]
},

"production" : {
  "rev": true
},

"critical" : {
  "src": "*.html",
  "width": 1920,
  "height": 1080
},

"favicon": {
  "src": ".",
  "name": "favicon.ico",
  "dest": "."
}
```

}
}

**Error**

ERROR in ./src/js/app.js
Module build failed: TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.dirname (path.js:695:5)
    at C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekty\Project\wp-content\themes\theme\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:353:36
    at C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekty\Project\wp-content\themes\theme\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:375:22
    at Array.map (native)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekty\Project\wp-content\themes\theme\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:364:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekty\Project\wp-content\themes\theme\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:348:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekty\Project\wp-content\themes\theme\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:307:14)
    at C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekty\Project\wp-content\themes\theme\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:349:14
    at C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekty\Project\wp-content\themes\theme\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:369:24
    at Array.map (native)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekty\Project\wp-content\themes\theme\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:364:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekty\Project\wp-content\themes\theme\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:348:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekty\Project\wp-content\themes\theme\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:307:14)
    at OptionManager.init (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekty\Project\wp-content\themes\theme\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:465:10)
    at File.initOptions (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekty\Project\wp-content\themes\theme\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:194:75)
    at new File (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekty\Project\wp-content\themes\theme\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:123:22)
    at Pipeline.transform (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekty\Project\wp-content\themes\theme\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:45:16)
    at transpile (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekty\Project\wp-content\themes\theme\node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:14:22)
    at Object.module.exports (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekty\Project\wp-content\themes\theme\node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:88:12)
 @ multi app